# React redux - фильтрация

Tags: веб-программирование, сортировка, redux, reactjs

Изучаю Redux и возникли сложности. Есть вот такой код:

Код редьюсера `items`:

```
const initialState = [];

export default function items(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_ITEMS': return action.payload;
        case 'SORT_ITEMS': return action.payload;
        default: return state
    }
}
```

Код редьюсера `filter`:

```
const initialState = '';

export default function filter(state = initialState, action) {
     switch (action.type) {
           case 'FIND_ITEMS': return action.payload;
           default: return state
    }
}
```

Код компонента:

```
export default connect(
    state => ({
        list: state.items.filter(item => item.name.includes(state.filter))
    }), 
    dispatch => ({
        onGetItems: () => {
            dispatch(getItems());
        },

        onFindItems: (text) => {
            dispatch({type: 'FIND_ITEMS', payload: text})
        },

        onSortItems: (items) => {
            dispatch({type: 'SORT_ITEMS', payload: items.reverse()})
        }
    })
)(App);
```

Необходимо отфильтровать значения.

`onGetItems` - получает с REST API данные и передаёт их в `state`.

`onFindItems` - фильтруем то, что написано в инпут.

`onSortItems` - необходимо разместить элементы массива в обратном порядке.

Два первых действия отрабатывают на "Ура", третье ноль реакции.

Comment: Вся суть в редьюсерах - добавьте их код. Хотя, как по мне, всё немного странно. Почему не фильтровать при рендеринге? Но может вы так и делаете, а `FIND_ITEMS` всего лишь сохраняет строку фильтра. Но почему `SORT_ITEMS` принимает список элементов?

Comment: А что он должен принимать? Первая сортировка по алфавиту происходит при рендере. Есть чекбокс, при чекнутом состоянии которого должна происходит сортировка в обратном порядке.

Comment: Сортировкой надо заниматься ли бо в редьюсере, либо при рендере. Action - это только команда. Например: `{type: 'SORT_ITEMS', payload: {order: 'reverse'}}`. Так и сортируйте в зависимости от состояния чекбокса